# How to handle excess space in conditional bullets in Jekyll docs via liquid

Tags: if-statement, jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll docs (theme: `just-the-docs`) and I'm trying to use liquid conditional statements to hide/unhide a bullet based on a site variable:

```
1. Bullet 1
{% if site.variable == "true" %}1. Bullet 2{% endif %}  
1. Bullet 3
1. Bullet 4
```

This works as intended when the `site.variable == "true"`. However, when the bullet is supposed to be hidden (`site.variable == "false"`) an extra newline shows instead of the "Bullet 2" output, i.e. as below:

```
1. Bullet 1

2. Bullet 3
3. Bullet 4
```

Any idea how to avoid this extra newline - while at same time enabling the conditional display of Bullet 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Liquid whitespace control/strip](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/)

```
  1. Bullet 1
  {%- if page.variable == true %}
  1. Bullet 2
  {%- endif %}
  1. Bullet 3
  1. Bullet 4
```